# Aggregate GroupBy columns with "all"-like function pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate-functions

I have a dataframe with a primary key, date, variable, and value. I want to group by the primary key and determine if all values are equal to a provided value. Example data:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "pk": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    "date": [
        date("2022-05-06"),
        date("2022-05-13"),
        date("2022-05-06"),
        date("2022-05-06"),
        date("2022-05-14"),
        date("2022-05-15"),
        date("2022-05-05"),
        date("2022-05-05"),
        date("2022-05-11"),
        date("2022-05-12")
    ],
    "variable": [A, B, C, D, A, A, E, F, A, G],
    "value": [2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4]
})

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

df.show()

df1.show()

#+-----+-----------+--------+-----+
#|pk   |       date|variable|value|
#+-----+-----------+--------+-----+
#|    1| 2022-05-06|       A|    2|
#|    1| 2022-05-13|       B|    3|
#|    1| 2022-05-06|       C|    2|
#|    1| 2022-05-06|       D|    2|
#|    2| 2022-05-14|       A|    1|
#|    2| 2022-05-15|       A|    1|
#|    2| 2022-05-05|       E|    1|
#|    2| 2022-05-05|       F|    1|
#|    3| 2022-05-11|       A|    5|
#|    4| 2022-05-12|       G|    4|
#+-----+-----------+--------+-----+
```

So if I want to know whether, given a primary key, `pk`, all the values are equal to 1 (or any arbitrary Boolean test), how should I do this? I've tried performing an `applyInPandas` but that is not super efficient and it seems like there is probably a pretty simply method to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Spark 3.+, you could use [`forall`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#forall) function to check if all values collected by `collect_list` satisfy the boolean test.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = (df
       .groupby("pk")
       .agg(F.expr("forall(collect_list(value), v -> v == 1)").alias("value"))
       )
df1.show()
# +---+-----+
# | pk|value|
# +---+-----+
# |  1|false|
# |  3|false|
# |  2| true|
# |  4|false|
# +---+-----+

# or create a column using window function
df2 = df.withColumn("test", F.expr("forall(collect_list(value) over (partition by pk), v -> v == 1)"))
df2.show()
# +---+----------+--------+-----+-----+
# | pk|      date|variable|value| test|
# +---+----------+--------+-----+-----+
# |  1|2022-05-06|       A|    2|false|
# |  1|2022-05-13|       B|    3|false|
# |  1|2022-05-06|       C|    2|false|
# |  1|2022-05-06|       D|    2|false|
# |  3|2022-05-11|       A|    5|false|
# |  2|2022-05-14|       A|    1| true|
# |  2|2022-05-15|       A|    1| true|
# |  2|2022-05-05|       E|    1| true|
# |  2|2022-05-05|       F|    1| true|
# |  4|2022-05-12|       G|    4|false|
# +---+----------+--------+-----+-----+
```

You might want to put it inside a `case` clause to handle NULL values.

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful. Do you happen to know if this would work with a window function? I'd like to keep the same rows after aggregation, but performing joins can be kind of expensive, and I need to do this for several columns.